# How can I check how many visitors are visiting my website?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I've a software developer having done most of my work in older technology stacks, and recently mobile iOS development. However I really know nothing about web other than a bit of HTML and interacting with web API's.

I recently purchased an out of the box template website to serve as a launching page for an application of mine. I would like to find out how many people are visiting my landing page. What's the best way to do this? Just go out and find some javascript applet that will do this for me? Where is the data/running-count stored? Or should my hosting provider (namecheap) provide this information to me automatically?

Comment: You can sign into your namecheap cpanel and monitor all this information.

Answer (score 4):

Install some sort of analytics script. A good one is [Google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

Comment: Do you know if Google Analytics provides accurate information for Standard analytics accounts, or is it still sampled? Either way, for the OP it should be more than sufficient for now.

Comment: Unsampled data is available for premium accounts only but there are ways you can analyze better in free accounts too. One of the way is export data for small data range such as 7 days or less (although its little pain).

Answer (score 1):

Its common for webhosting providers to have some sort of analytics engine running like awstats or webanalyzer.

Also you could create a free account in [Google Analytics](http://www.google.cl/analytics/) and follow the instruction to add a snippet of code to your page to count your visits.

Now if you also want to show a visit counter, the best alternative is to make it with some server side code and a database (or a file). It is relatively easy and if you post your server infrastructure (php, asp, mysql,postgres, etc) i could expand this answer with more help.